# Can't pass an array of objects to a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have written this directive

```
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp2', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {templateUrl: 'page1.html', controller: 'page1Controller'})
        .when('/page2', {templateUrl: 'page2.html', controller: 'page2Controller'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/page1'})
});

app.directive('mymenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            menuItems: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'menu.html'
    };
});
app.controller('page1Controller', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{title: "Menu Item1", address: "/page3.html"}, {title: "Menu Item2", address: "/page4.html"}]
});

app.controller('page2Controller', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{title: "Menu Item3", address: "/page5.html"}, {title: "Menu Item4", address: "/page6.html"}]
});
```

The template of the directive is

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>My Menu</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <td><a href="{{item.address}}">{{item.title}}</a></td>          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I am trying to use it like this

```
<div>
<mymenu menuItems="{{menuItems}}"></mymenu>
</div>
```

But it only prints the table header but no items. I also tried using a menItems: '@' but still it shows nothing.

My hope was that the {{menuItems}} would pass the array and then the menItems: '=' would assign it to the internal scope of the directive ...

In my main page I removed the {{menuItems}} and called my directive as  but still the same issue.

Comment: Answer updated once again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simplified answer:**

You'll have to change the html attribute from menuItems to menu-items as it automagically converts to slash-case, and you'll have to remove the curly braces as the = sign expects a reference to an object instead of the value of it. Your code should look like this:

```
<mymenu menu-items="menuItems"></mymenu>
```

**More detailed:**

One thing to note is that when you use the = sign at the directive scope declaration, it means you'll get a reference of that object, so if by any chance you change the value of it, changes will be propagated to the view controller.

The second thing to note is that camelCased directive names or attributes from directive scopes convert automagically to slash-cased. That was decided by the AngularJS team as HTML code is not case sensitive to identify the change.

Live sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/R3TIxLGmzCsXmJh8qtFc?p=preview

View

```
<div ng-view></div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page1.html"><mymenu menu-items="menuItems"></mymenu></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page2.html">Page 2!</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page3.html">page 3!</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page4.html">Page 4!</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu.html">
  <table>
    <thead>
        <th>My Menu</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <td><a href="{{item.address}}">{{item.title}}</a></td>          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp2', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'page1.html', controller: 'page1Controller'})
        .when('/page2', {templateUrl: 'page2.html', controller: 'page2Controller'})
        .when('/page3', {templateUrl: 'page3.html'})
        .when('/page4', {templateUrl: 'page4.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
});

app.directive('mymenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            menuItems: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'menu.html'
    };
});

app.controller('page1Controller', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{title: "Menu Item1", address: "/page3.html"}, {title: "Menu Item2", address: "/page4.html"}]
});

app.controller('page2Controller', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{title: "Menu Item3", address: "/page5.html"}, {title: "Menu Item4", address: "/page6.html"}]
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: I made the change you mentioned... but it still only shows the header of table... but no array data..

Comment: I'll check it on plunkr and post a link when done, it looks like the rest of the code is ok but there's probably something else there

Comment: I can see that it works... but you have done more than just use the = sign. You changed the attribute from menuItems to items. I think angular does not like menuItems... it likes menuitems (without captials).

Comment: New plnkr with changes... if you want to use menuItems as a scope from the directive, when you use it inside the HTML you will have to convert it from cammelCase to slashed-case, same applies to directive names
http://plnkr.co/edit/R3TIxLGmzCsXmJh8qtFc?p=preview